# Сколько главных и придаточных в этом предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

Сколько главных и придаточных в этом предложении? (запишите цифрой, например 1, 4.) 
В разоренной и сожженной Москве Пьер испытал почти крайние пределы лишений, которые может переносить человек; но, благодаря своему сильному сложению и здоровью, которого он не сознавал до сих пор, и в особенности благодаря тому, что эти лишения подходили так незаметно, что нельзя было сказать, когда они начались, он переносил не только легко, но и радостно свое положение.

Comment: Мы не выполняем дом. задания. Предложите и объясните свой вариант решения.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Сколько главных и придаточных в этом предложении?
```

[1.В разоренной и сожженной Москве Пьер испытал почти крайние пределы лишений], (2. которые может переносить человек); но,[3.благодаря своему сильному сложению и здоровью, (4.которого он не сознавал до сих пор), и в особенности благодаря тому, (5.что эти лишения подходили так незаметно),(6.что нельзя было сказать), (7.когда они начались),3. он переносил не только легко, но и радостно свое положение].

Вся конструкция() 7 простых предложений - два сложноподчинённых предложения, соединённых союзом НО.

Два главных(1 и 3),5 придаточных(2,4,5,6,7), однако это не совсем точно, потому что во втором сложноподчинённом 5, 6 и 7 придаточные соединены последовательно, а значит,5 является главным для 6, а 6 для 7-ого.Получается, 4 главных и 5 придаточных. Так что сами решайте, что именно вам нужно.